# jquery.mobile-1.4.4.js interfering with body theme

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

The jquery mobile class jquery.mobile-1.4.4.css is interfering with my body class. How can I change the theme so that my body class theme is default.

Here is the code for my body class theme

```
 body
 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: grey !important;    
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked perfectly.. I copied and pasted the code from the jquery css class to my css file and changed the color to suit mine. Here is the code:

```
 .ui-overlay-a,
 .ui-page-theme-a,
 .ui-page-theme-a .ui-panel-wrapper {
 background-color: grey !important; 
 background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
 background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile creates a page DIV that covers the entire screen, so if you want, you can apply your gradient background to the page:

```
body, div[data-role="page"]
{
      margin: 0 auto;
      background-color: grey !important;    
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(white, grey); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
      background: linear-gradient(white, grey); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qLjj9zjy/)**